# Passing method parameters from EJB3 to EJB2 is not happening

Tags: java, ejb, parameter-passing, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

I have EJB3 and EJB2 bean. I am calling a method which is there in EJB2 from EJB3 bean.

Below is the code in EJB3 bean.

```
private EJB2ServiceRemote getEJB2Bean() {
    if (EJB2ServiceRemote == null) {
      EJBHomeAttributes EJB2Service =
          new EJBHomeAttributes("ejb/business/payments/EJB2Service", EJB2ServiceRemoteHome.class.getName());
      EJB2ServiceRemote = (EJB2ServiceRemote) EJBServices.getRemoteService(EJB2Service);
    }
    return EJB2ServiceRemote;
  }



String result = getEJB2Bean().callMethodInEJB2(withSomeParameter);
```

My problem is `withSomeParameter` is going as `null` in `callMethodInEJB2` in EJB2 Bean.

I am using Websphere 7 application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is withSomeparameter a Serializable type?

if not, you cannot send it to a Remote EJB call, it has to be a serializable type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `withSomeParameter implements Serializable`. Even then it is going as `null`

Comment: Solved it by changing EJB2ServiceRemote  to Local